# international journal forecasting template article

Tags: templates, article

Where can I find the template for an article with the structure of the IJF?

Attached the link to see an example

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207014001083

You just click on top "download pdf" and automatically will download the article with the format and structured I am looking for.

I tried all the latex templates pages but couldn't find a similar one with the article info and abstract in two columns, the content in full width and again the article in two columns.

Thanks for the support!!!

Comment: they do list an email-address in the .pdf. Maybe you should contact them?

Answer (score 2):

[This guide for authors wishing to submit a paper to the IJF](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/international-journal-of-forecasting/0169-2070/guide-for-authors) says that is recommended to use [elsarticle.cls](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle). There's a link to a [LaTeX dedicated page](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the guidelines for authors and additional info was already checked. No way to find out the exact template.

Comment: @José `elsarticle` will not produce the exact output as in the journal, but that's how things work: the copy editors will change some details and produce the final output.

Comment: On the LaTeX dedicated page it says "Although elsarticle.cls supports most journal styles, it is not possible to match the journal's layout exactly.", so you won't find the exact layout/class/template. If you want to submit an article, you shouldn't even try because "Custom layout will be removed." and " The text should be in single-column format.". If you want it for something else, it's not that much of a problem to replicate the layout.

Comment: Ok, guys!!! Got it!!! I was interested in to replicate the layout but without the template would be difficult for me.Thanks anyway for your time and regards!!!

Answer (score 1):

The preferred template is given on the journal website at https://forecasters.org/ijf/authors/